# I can't figure out to start glassfish within netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

When I click on Run it displays the following error message:

```
Starting GlassFish v3 Domain
GlassFish v3 Domain start failed.
/Volumes/Private/noname/Sites/projects/java/MyFirstServlet/nbproject/build-impl.xml:602: Deployment error:
GlassFish v3 Domain start failed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 minutes 0 seconds)
```

But then I fire up Terminal in mac and use asadmin start-domain and it starts.

And in netbeans I then Run the project and it fires up Safari and displays the content.

But why can't glassfish start in netbeans? Any idea?

Comment: Please, provide the full error/trace, my crystal ball isn't working well those days.

Comment: >> See the server log for details.  << the content of this could be useful.

Comment: if the file server.log is what they mean in the domain folder than i cant see anything regarding that issue.

Comment: My server sometimes fails to start when another instance is already running... Re-start your IDE and kill all java tasks can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met the same problem as I was learning java web programming, but in windows env. I've spent much time guessing what that error could mean because the log file wasn't clearly saying that. Finally I found out that glassfish v3 was trying to run on 8080 port, which was already occupied by reportingservicesservice.exe which is sql server service. I didn't get to know how to switch the port used by glassfish, but I found that in netbeans 6.8 (which I use) in tools->servers I can add a new glassfish server instance which runs on a different, free port - that solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with the port 8080, when I type `http://localhost:8080`, I  found that oracle 10g was using it first before I install netbeans 6.8 with glassfish, I deleted oracle database 10g and, wich made the 8080 port free, and now everything is fine, it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Netbeans IDE X.X --> Tools --> Servers
```

Add `Server --> Choose Server --> GlassFish 3.X`

then click (next) browse installation location click (next)

```
select (register local domain) domain name : domain 2
```

click on finish button

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and it happened because of a version mismatch between the local server (Glassfish 4.**1**) and the remote (Glassfish 4.**0**).

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to my mind is to check if the JAVA_HOME is properly set. Guess GFv3 requires it to be set to the bin folder in the JDK installation. Just guessing...

Answer (score 0):

Go to following link there i've wrote solution for it...

http://forums.netbeans.org/post-65058.html

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem with both glassfish and tomcat in netbeans 6.9. My problem and solution were both simple. The problem: tomcat was already running on my machine on port 8080 and therefore netbeans could not create a new instance of either. The solution: shutdown the running instance of tomcat and let netbeans start it up for you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the port of glassfish. To do this:
join `C:\Program Files\SEMS-v3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config` open the file domain.xml
and change the text in 8080 by 9999.

After you do this, enter the remove server netbeans glassfish glassfish addServer then add it so that it can recognize the port changed. Then Started On glassfish server, then run your project.

Here is the link: http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/changeglassfishport.asp

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, here are the steps I followed to solve it:

- remove the glassfish server under "Services > Servers"
- close projet and Netbeans
- locate the install directory of Glassfish and go to domains (GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains).
- delete the "domain1" directory
- start Netbeans
- recreate a Glassfish server
- Don't forget to recreate your data sources and connection pools

Answer (score 0):

i have start to learn java recently,i have encountered the same problem too but i found out that when the first time the guidebook ask me to add a server, i put in user and password.
so i give another try to remove the server and add it again without the password.
and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved by configuring my netbeans config file. 
Find NetBeans 8.2\etc\Netbeans.conf file and search for this line :

netbeans_default_options="

Add --locale en to the end before quotes. Eventually this line looks like:
disableMemoryMapping=true --locale en".
Restart Netbeans...